# Drupal Multiple upload images Manual Cropping not saving cropped images in database only first image is saving

Tags: drupal

I am using Drupal manual cropping this is cropping uploaded images. Cropped image is saving only in single upload case but when I chose multiple images cropped images are not saving in db only original images are saving that is not require.

Comment: Please add information about which cropping module you are using, which version of Drupal, and if you are using multiple image fields or one image field with multiple values.

Comment: Hi acrosman Thanks for your given me value able time.
I am using manual cropping contributed module.
when i upload only one image then it is cropping and cropped image part it is saving in database and also in folder. But when i am uploading multiple image using multiupload module then in that case only first image cropped  and cropped image part is saving in db and folder and rest other images not cropping and not saving only thumb nail is showing that cropped image size but when i check it via inspect behind this original image is showing.
Please give me any solution for this problem.